# Android Studio Getting Crash on Linux

Tags: android, linux, crash, linux-mint

i'm using linux mint. now i'm facing this problem i can't even find solution. 
hope someone help me here.

**System configuration.**

*Operating System : Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon

Cinnamon Version : 3.8.7

Linux Kernal : 4.15

Processor : AMD FX(tm)-8150

RAM : 8GB*

**here is crash details.**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f8550bde9ca, pid=20860, tid=0x00007f84cb8ce700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_152-b01) (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.152-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 46464 C1 com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.view.LineLayout$SingleChunk.getChunksInLogicalOrder()Ljava/util/stream/Stream; (21 bytes) @ 0x00007f8550bde9ca [0x00007f8550bde4c0+0x50a]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Comment: Hi bro, Did u get the answer?

Comment: not yet. but also i mail to google they still not found :D

Comment: i got the answer wait i will post

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have faced the same problem,And finally i found the solution for it.Actually in my case while i am try to checkout the subversion in android studio fully crashed.I mean it was closed unexpectedly.I spend the lot of time of it.

Go to your home directory like **home/vijay(your path)** then **Ctrl + H**.It will show your all hidden files in there **just delete the following files**.

- .android
- .java
- .subversion
- .gradle

> **Note : Do these stuffs before open android studio.**

Then open android studio it will work sure.

> **Don't worry if you delete also it will create automatically.**